# JSF convertDateTime render timestamp wrong

Tags: datetime, jsf, primefaces, format, converters

PrimeFaces 6.1, WebLogic 12cR2

I'm trying list out a bunch of entities in . Data was kept in PostgreSQL, xhtml snippet as:

```
<p:dateTable>
   ......
<p:column headerText="#{clientpayment['web.payment.label.created']}">
  <h:outputText value="#{payment.created}">
  <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd MMM yy HH:MM:SS.mmm" />
</h:outputText></p:column>
   .......
</p:dataTable>
```

JSF default locale was set to my system locale in web.xml configure file:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Entity was declared as:

```
@Basic
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@javax.persistence.Column(name = "created", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true)
private Date created;
public Date getCreated() {
    return created;
}
public void setCreated(Date created) {
    this.created = created;
}
```

Database shows timestamp as:

[image]

seams the data was kept in good order.

But when I run application the result is very funny. Only year, month, date and seconds info rendering properly, any thing else (hour,minute and milliseconds) were wrong.

[image]

Any idea about the funny thing? Is it a bug or some thing wrong in my application? Please advise!!

Comment: Does it work if not used in a PrimeFaces datatable?

Answer (score 0):

Date time format inside *pattern* attribute of your *f:convertDateTime* element is not correct.

It should be **dd MMM yy HH:mm:ss.SSS**

Comment: @cidy.long Did you maybe try, just for testing purposes, to apply some other date time format? For example, dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss. Does it give correct output?

Comment: Tried. Nothing different.

Comment: Then you are most likely not running the code you think you are running